# Convertendo int em string

Tags: c, string, int

fiz um programinha que simula um login e ao converter a senha que esta em int para string usando sprintf ele da segimentation falt, tentei usar a itoa mas ele da erro de definição

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char login[6]={0};

   int passwd;
   char senha[6]={0};

   char logins[6]="Teste";
   char senhas[6]="12345";

  do{
     printf("\n\tDigite o Login: ");
     scanf("%s",login);

     if((strcmp(login, logins) == 0))break;
     else
     printf("\tUsuario: %s Inválido..!!\n", login);

     }while((strcmp(login, logins) != 0));

  do{
     printf("\n\tDigite sua senha: ");
     scanf("%d",passwd);

     sprintf(senha,"%s",passwd);

     if((strcmp(senha, senhas) == 0))
     printf("\n\tUsuario e Senha Válidos\n\tAcesso autorizado..!!!\n\n");
       else
     printf("\tSenha: %s Inválida..!!\n", senha);

    }while((strcmp(senha, senhas) != 0));

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Se a senha é um `int` porque precisa de ser convertida para `string` ? Se é suposto ser uma `string` porque não ler `string` diretamente ?

Comment: pq esse é outra forma de usar comparação para fazer login, e preciso entao verificar se a senha for int converte em char* compara e faz login se for iguais mas nao to conseguindo converter essa senha para string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 printf(senha,"%s",passwd);
```

O "%s" so deve ser utilizado caso passwd fosse uma array de caractereres(char[]) como é um inteiro utilize "%d"

Entretanto utilize a função snprintf, ela evita segmentation fault, aquele 6 ali é o tamanho da sua array, dado o tamanho da sua array, a função nunca ira escrever mais que o permitido.

```
snprintf(senha, 6, "%d", passwd);
```

**ITOA (Dado que nenhuma solução acima funcionou)**

Ja que a lib do seu compilador não tem a funcão para converter int para char*, vamos criar uma!!!:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *  itoa ( int value, char * str )
{
    char temp;
    int i =0;
    while (value > 0) {
        int digito = value % 10;

        str[i] = digito + '0';
        value /= 10;
        i++;

    }
   i = 0;
   int j = strlen(str) - 1;

   while (i < j) {
      temp = str[i];
      str[i] = str[j];
      str[j] = temp;
      i++;
      j--;
   }
    return str;


}

int main()
{
   char login[6]={0};

   int passwd;
   char senha[6]={0};

   char logins[6]="Teste";
   char senhas[6]="12345";



  do{
     printf("\n\tDigite o Login: ");
     scanf("%s",login);

     if((strcmp(login, logins) == 0))break;
     else
     printf("\tUsuario: %s Inválido..!!\n", login);

     }while((strcmp(login, logins) != 0));

  do{
     printf("\n\tDigite sua senha: ");
     scanf("%d",&passwd);

     //sprintf(senha,"%s",passwd);
     //snprintf(senha, 6, "%d", passwd);
      itoa(passwd,senha);

     if((strcmp(senha, senhas) == 0))
     printf("\n\tUsuario e Senha Válidos\n\tAcesso autorizado..!!!\n\n");
       else
     printf("\tSenha: %s Inválida..!!\n", senha);

    }while((strcmp(senha, senhas) != 0));

   return 0;
}
```

Testado e funcionando.
No scanf tem que passar a variável por referencia ficando assim:

```
scanf("%d",&passwd);
```

amostra da execução do codigo acima online 
https://onlinegdb.com/SkcoQAIbf

Comment: entao eu tentei usar tambem esse snprintf e o sprintf tanto com %d quando com %s e mesmo assim resultaram em falhas de segmentação, tentei até mesmo usar a função std::to_string e copiando a mesma para o array de char e mesmo assim deu falha de segmentação, porem se eu declarar o passwd como um ponteiro ele nao da falha de segmentação mas na hora de digitar a senha ele me retorna valor 90 ou seja ele faz uma soma da senha e multiplica pelo tamanho do valor do array... nao sei mas o que fazer pra converter int para string a função itoa nao existe mais no compilador gcc-g++ 7.2.0...

Comment: acho que agr vai amigo, dessa vez sem utilizar sprintf ou alguma função do tipo.

Comment: entao @Vitorrisk e se eu te disser que nao foi ainda assim da falha de segmentação? ja vi essa função pesquisando sobre a itoa e tentei adaptar tambem no meu codigo tanto essa quanto a outra versao da itoa onde vc entra com o length para dizer o tamanho do vetor e mesmo assim deu falha de segmentação... ja usei tanto  a: itoa(int, char*) quanto a itoa(char*, const char*, int); e mesmo assim deu falha de segmentação, ta dificil entender essa bagaça...

Comment: executei no site https://onlinegdb.com/ o seguinte o seguinte codigo abaixo com as ediçoes sugeridas e mesmo assim da segmentation falt. https://pastebin.com/rydbmF9f

Comment: agora ta ok https://onlinegdb.com/B1dz7AIbM

Comment: o unico erro do seu codigo foi :  scanf("%d",passwd) repare que passwd esta sendo passada como valor e não como referencia, fiz tempestade em copo da agua

Comment: caraca era só isso? que legal aprendi que referencia nao era nescessario fazer principalmente quando se estava trabalhando com string... caraca valeu agora sim rodei aqui e ta funfando mesmo...