# Converter valor recebido como int para o tipo char em C

Tags: c, string

Eu estou fazendo um trabalho da faculdade em que tenho que converter um valor recebido para char para que eu possa escrevê-lo por extenso por exemplo. Me ajudem a criar essa função.

Comment: Mostra para nós o que você já tentou(em forma de código) e onde tem dúvida..

Answer (score 1):

Um caracter só pode representar um número de 0 a 9.
Caso queira converter um número superior a 9 em uma `string` veja: [Convertendo int em string](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/260415/convertendo-int-em-string)

Caso realmente queria um inteiro como `char`, você pode fazer isso da seguinte forma:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int inteiro = 1;  
    char caractere = inteiro+'0';

    printf("%c",caractere);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja mais explicações: [Converting int to char in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46006861/converting-int-to-char-in-c)